# Populate asp.net treeview from clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I am working on asp.net application. Where for a page I have to populate a treeview from clientside. I dont have any idea as where to start from. Any sample or any reference link will be of great help.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is the client side population a must? Are you comfortable with JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Comment: Yes clientside is must. The requirement is to populate the asp:treeview from clientside. it may be any way through javascript or through jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TreeView.PopulateNodesFromClient property of the asp:TreeView to true, allowing population of the control from the client. This link shows a good example of how to handle the client side population: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.populatenodesfromclient(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.populatenodesfromclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)